# TeamCity Pre-release Nuget of Application Insights Fails

Tags: teamcity, nuget

I added the pre-release version of Application Insights to my build. The build works fine in VisualStudio after installing all of the Nuget packages, not quite the "2 clicks" advertised by Microsoft, but not bad in VS2013.

I am now trying to build the website in TeamCity and getting failures indicating Nuget cannot find the package during a pre-compile Nuget Update pass. The error is: Unable to find version '0.8.0-build10578' of package 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

I have pre-release selected in the TeamCity configuration and have added the microsoft feed URL to the build's configuration just to be sure (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/)
Any ideas where the problem might lie?

Comment: Please try to execute 'nuget restore' command via .NET process runner on build agent. Make sure that it works.